# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Slim\Slim' not found

Tags: php, slim, reset

This is an excerpt of my index.php
I have composer installed but I keep getting class sim not found.

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'templates.path' => '../templates'
));

$app->get('/api', function () use ($app) {
    // Get the start and end timestamps from request query parameters
    $startTimestamp = $app->request->get('start');
    $endTimestamp = $app->request->get('end');

    try {
        // Open database connection
        $conn = new \PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=calendar', 'root', '');

        // Query database for events in range
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE start >= FROM_UNIXTIME(:start) AND end < FROM_UNIXTIME(:end) ORDER BY start ASC');
        $stmt->bindParam(':start', $startTimestamp, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':end', $endTimestamp, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        // Fetch query results 
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Return query results as JSON
        echo json_encode($results);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        $app->halt(500, $e->getMessage());
   }
});
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('calendar.html');
});
$app->run();
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to implement the Full Calendar jquery plugin

Comment: This is caused by a typo. The class name is `\Slim\App` not `\Slim\Slim`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You could verify your installed packages `composer info -i`

2 - Peraps you make a tipo `new \Slim\Slim`

Try

```
$app = new \Slim\App(array(
    'templates.path' => '../templates'
));
```

Comment: slim\slim is installed. Worked when I used \App. But now I'm getting "Slim Application Error" "A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience." How do i find out whats causing this error?

Comment: I don't know this framwork but I take a look to the documentation: your code look like version 2 of the framwork and you certenly have a version 3 installed

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using version 2 and the site worked.